# Can an coaxial antenna cable transmit internet data like telephone line?

Tags: networking, cable

If I use an coaxial antenna cable instead of telephone cable to transmit internet data, will it be functional rather than using telephone cable? Or do any disconnections occur?

Note: Max provided speed by telecom is 8mbps and I'll use antenna cable to connect the outside line to ADSL modem. Coaxial cable's resistivity is 75±3Ω.

Comment: Not likely to work because of the impedance mismatch.  You could try attaching UTP-to-coax baluns (if that exists) on each end, but installing phone cable would probably be cheaper and guaranteed to work.  BTW 75 Ohms is the *impedance* of the coax cable, not its *resistance* (which is much lower and is a function of length).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "...connect the outside line to ADSL modem?" Are you trying to get your aDSL line to an outbuilding, or are you referring to the Telco's entrance point when you say "outside line?"

Comment: I've meant, I live on a seperate house. So, I have single line for adsl from telecom. I've asked that can coax cables tranmit the data. Whatever sawdust answered. Thank you. @BillOer

Comment: Thanks @sawdust. Can you answer my post with your comment please?

Comment: You should ask the Telco to move the outside connection point to where you need it. They are normally responsible for any wiring outside the premises and if you do it yourself you are likely to screw up the ADSL.

Comment: Normally the telco is responsible for getting the line to the property. If the lines needs to be extended somewhere else on that property, which seems to be the case here, it is the subscriber's responsibility. I would suggest suspending the IW (Inside Wire) in polyester or nylon twine. Get a ball that can be played out from the center, run the wire inside the ball, attach the twine to the wire, and the twine will wrap around the wire as it goes through the ball of twine. Do not try to suspend IW by itself.